# What does a green icon mean and why do the package bodies not expand when they have it?

Tags: oracle-10g, oracle-sql-developer

In SQLDeveloper 4 some 10g PL/SQL packages have a regular crate while others have a green dot.

Those with the green dot do not expand their bodies (might be just a coincidence). What is the difference between the packages with and w/o a green dot and why do some packages not expand their bodies?

[image]

Comment: No source code?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I mean that for the packages you can't expand, maybe the source code isn't available?

Comment: Not the case. Both have PLENTY of source code and hundreds of procedures and functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The green *bug* you're seeing (look closely) means the package have been compiled with DEBUG option. It is also seen on bare procedures and functions. It is a coincidence they don't expand - maybe a bug (duh) in SQLdeveloper :) On mine, these expand without problem.